# How do I use an if/else statement with WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use a different WP_Query object depending on what type of page is being viewed. I'd like to do it without having to repeat the loop over and over again. I just want to use different WP_Query statements with a conditional. Is this possible, or is there another way to do this? Right now I'm only getting empty output on my pages. Code is below.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

// retrieve posts based on category or pages
$args=array(
    'category_name'=>'name',
    'posts_per_page'=>10,
    'paged'=>$paged
);

if (is_page()) {        
    //create a new instance
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
}

else {
    //create a new instance
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
}

// the Loop
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

// set $more to 0 in order to only get the first part of the post
global $more;
$more = 0;

// Do post layout here

endwhile;
```

Comment: Why wrap `if`s in brackets, but not the `while`.

Comment: It's due to the fact that wordpress code out of the box usually uses endwhile/endif for loops, and a lot of other stuff in brackets. I just got used to working that way.

Comment: you might want to adopt one or the other. A mix of both usually means that two or more people have worked on it and the project manager never set a standard to follow (BIG problem)

Comment: This is for a personal site. I'm not a coder by trade and the only one that will ever work on this will be me. Although I realize that you're probably right and I appreciate your advice, at the moment I'm just trying to get this particular issue resolved. I'll take what you've said into consideration in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$my_args = is_page() ? $args : null;

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  ...
```

`$wp_query` is a [global variable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables). Avoid use it for those things.